# Transmission issues after latest update

Tags: raspbian

Since last update of system getting some strange issues preventing me from starting transmission.

```
Setting up transmission-daemon (2.92-2+deb9u1) ...
Job for transmission-daemon.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status transmission-daemon.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript transmission-daemon, action "start" failed.
● transmission-daemon.service - Transmission BitTorrent Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-12-30 19:11:50 GMT; 33ms ago
  Process: 23213 ExecStop=/bin/kill -s STOP $MAINPID (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 23211 ExecStart=/usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error (code=exited, status=127)
 Main PID: 23211 (code=exited, status=127)

Dec 30 19:11:50 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Transmission BitTorrent Daemon...
Dec 30 19:11:50 raspberrypi systemd[1]: transmission-daemon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Dec 30 19:11:50 raspberrypi systemd[1]: transmission-daemon.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 30 19:11:50 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Transmission BitTorrent Daemon.
Dec 30 19:11:50 raspberrypi systemd[1]: transmission-daemon.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 30 19:11:50 raspberrypi systemd[1]: transmission-daemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package transmission-daemon (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 transmission-daemon
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Ive uninstalled and reinstalled transmission and still have same issue. 
`journalctl -xe` gives the following log:

```
Dec 30 19:11:50 raspberrypi kill[23213]:  -l, --list=[<signal>]  list all signal names, or convert one to a name
Dec 30 19:11:50 raspberrypi kill[23213]:  -L, --table            list all signal names in a nice table
Dec 30 19:11:50 raspberrypi kill[23213]:  -h, --help     display this help and exit
Dec 30 19:11:50 raspberrypi kill[23213]:  -V, --version  output version information and exit
Dec 30 19:11:50 raspberrypi kill[23213]: For more details see kill(1).
Dec 30 19:11:50 raspberrypi systemd[1]: transmission-daemon.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 30 19:11:50 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Transmission BitTorrent Daemon.
-- Subject: Unit transmission-daemon.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit transmission-daemon.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Dec 30 19:11:50 raspberrypi systemd[1]: transmission-daemon.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 30 19:11:50 raspberrypi systemd[1]: transmission-daemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 30 19:11:51 raspberrypi sudo[23141]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Dec 30 19:16:00 raspberrypi sudo[23324]:       pi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/pi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl stat
Dec 30 19:16:00 raspberrypi sudo[23324]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by pi(uid=0)
Dec 30 19:16:00 raspberrypi sudo[23324]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Dec 30 19:16:15 raspberrypi sudo[23337]:       pi : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/pi ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl star
Dec 30 19:16:15 raspberrypi sudo[23337]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by pi(uid=0)
Dec 30 19:16:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Transmission BitTorrent Daemon...
-- Subject: Unit transmission-daemon.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit transmission-daemon.service has begun starting up.
Dec 30 19:16:15 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[23343]: [99B blob data]
Dec 30 19:16:15 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[23343]: [56B blob data]
Dec 30 19:16:15 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[23343]: [78B blob data]
Dec 30 19:16:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: transmission-daemon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Dec 30 19:16:15 raspberrypi kill[23345]: Usage:
Dec 30 19:16:15 raspberrypi kill[23345]:  kill [options] <pid> [...]
Dec 30 19:16:15 raspberrypi kill[23345]: Options:
Dec 30 19:16:15 raspberrypi kill[23345]:  <pid> [...]            send signal to every <pid> listed
Dec 30 19:16:15 raspberrypi kill[23345]:  -<signal>, -s, --signal <signal>
Dec 30 19:16:15 raspberrypi kill[23345]:                         specify the <signal> to be sent
Dec 30 19:16:15 raspberrypi kill[23345]:  -l, --list=[<signal>]  list all signal names, or convert one to a name
Dec 30 19:16:15 raspberrypi kill[23345]:  -L, --table            list all signal names in a nice table
Dec 30 19:16:15 raspberrypi kill[23345]:  -h, --help     display this help and exit
Dec 30 19:16:15 raspberrypi kill[23345]:  -V, --version  output version information and exit
Dec 30 19:16:15 raspberrypi kill[23345]: For more details see kill(1).
Dec 30 19:16:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: transmission-daemon.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 30 19:16:15 raspberrypi sudo[23337]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Dec 30 19:16:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Transmission BitTorrent Daemon.
-- Subject: Unit transmission-daemon.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit transmission-daemon.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Dec 30 19:16:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: transmission-daemon.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 30 19:16:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: transmission-daemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

And whats really strange is when I just try the command `transmission-daemon` I get the following, which is a pain because I dont know which shared libraries are causing the issue:

```
V;�UK"���9�faemon: error while loading shared libraries: �0���tDJ@Y{��K
�A��S�s�@
          aB���@�(��
                      ���[�p�%@�G~�p�����l �e��%
\v�$Jijc�R�d ���: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

### EDIT

running `sudo ldconfig -v` 
gives me:

```
    ����l �e��%
\v�$Jijc�R�d ��� -> libcrypto.so.1.1
```

which looks like the link for libcrypto is broken. 
Tried uninstalling and reinstalling libssl-dev and openssl and rebuilding ldconfig with `sudo ldconfig` but that doesnt seem to have worked, link still seems corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right so I seem to have resolved my issue at the moment.

I removed `openssl` and `libssl-dev` - whether I needed to do these two things is debateable.

using `sudo ldconfig -v` gave me the corrupted link

```
    ����l �e��%
\v�$Jijc�R�d ��� -> libcrypto.so.1.1
```

and the location of the corrupted link

```
 broken link was under /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

so I went into that directory and removed all broken symlinks

```
cd /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf  
sudo find -L . -name . -o -type d -prune -o -type l -exec rm {} +
```

I went to the debian page for libssl https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libssl1.1 and downloaded the correct libssl library then rebuilt the ldconfig

```
wget http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.0j-1~deb9u1_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.0j-1~deb9u1_armhf.deb
sudo ldconfig
```

Now all seems to be okay.